# Disable ListView Scrolling to Top

Tags: android

I have a listview to which items are added dynamically to the top of the list. I show some latest events occurring at the top of the list. The problem is, these events occur very frequently, like 5 events in a second. This makes the list go down. Suppose user is looking at one event, then when new event occurs it pushes the event he was reading below, and that disappears. I want the new events to be added at the top but it should be shown only when he scrolls up. I call notifydatasetchanged on the adapter once new events occur and this pushes the list down. Is there anyway I can freeze the scrolling. I tried to disable the scrolling by  setTranscriptMode. But it doesn't seem to help. Kindly give me some hints and point me

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is try to get the visible position of ListView on the screen using [**getFirstVisiblePosition()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29) and then set the Adapter again with setSelection of position you got.

```
int position = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
mListView.setSelection(position + 1);
```

I guess you would need (position + 1) because you are adding items on top of the List for every single item added to List.

Answer (score 0):

To show latest events as you require you need to set `android:transcriptMode="normal"`
 This will by default set the focus to last item whenever data set is changed.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:transcriptMode

Also I you want to freeze scrolling then you can set `setOnScrollListener()`and update the list only then.